# JSON call not working (Android)

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to execute this JSON call as follows:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=dict_api.callbacks.id100&q=insouciant&sl=en&tl=en");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = null;
            try{
                responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
            }catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

            try {
                Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
                jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;
                System.out.println("JSONRESPONSE getCardsFromTagNames="+jsonObject);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, the returned result is NULL. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, any Network I/O should be a done in a separate thread and not on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is coming back wrapped in a function for use in a callback (`dict_api.callbacks.id100`). Given that this API doesn't seem to return anything if you omit the callback, you'll have to get your result string, and parse out the json part, then pass that on to your json parser.

Comment: thanks jbowes. could you perhaps explain this with an example?

Answer (score 2):

`resultBody` contains the callback function which is usually called by some JavaScript ([JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)).

As you don't need this function, you can easily strip it like this:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&q=insouciant&sl=en&tl=en");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = null;
try{
   responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
   responseBody = responseBody.substring(2, responseBody.length()-3);
}catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```